# Primeng Turbotable pagination default rows per page

Tags: angular, pagination, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I am using the Prime NG TurboTable Version 7.1.3 and currently have the `[rowsPerPageOptions]` set to `[5, 10, 20, 100]` my organization wants to set rows to 100 by default and be able to change the rows per page after that. My problem is that the GUI is still showing 5 when I open the page, even though it is showing more than 5 rows. Is there another setting that I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paginator has the `rows` property for that:

```
<p-table [paginator]="true"  [rows]="100" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5, 10, 20, 100]" ... >
    ...
</p-table>
```

Comment: You are correct, for some reason our code wasn't using the input [rows]="100", but rows="100". Thank you for your help.